# Privacy Policy for my App - asked by Client's Legal Department

Tags: privacy

My company has a B2B mobile app on iOS/Google Play. Our app links to our privacy policy on our corporate website which is encouraged/required by iOS/Android these days.

My Client needs to make sure their Users have accepted a privacy policy that is acceptable to their legal department. Since my app is used by many clients I am unwilling to have their privacy policy be displayed directly.

Their question is, when is an app user specifically signing into my apps privacy policy as it currently is?

I cannot see at any time my apps privacy policy is displayed directly to the user. I think it's just a link hidden away within the AppStore listing. How does Apple/Google deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. You are entirely responsible for at what time you show your privacy policy to your users.

Both Google/Apple show this privacy policy on the app's landing page, they did that in response to California's AG rattling with their figurative sabor years back. However none of that really solves your own problems of compliance.

Usually you [show a privacy policy in three spots](https://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-app-store-guide-link/), when you have an app (and a related website):

- the promotional website
- the app stores
- within the app

Now your case within the app then always depends. Do you need to show your privacy policy to your users for some reason, or is it enough to just have it sit there? That always depends.

Comment: This is a great link, and good advise thanks @Simon

Comment: you're very welcome @Markive